# running elastic search plugin grails 2.4.4 / 2.5.0

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-orm

I am trying to get the ealastic search plugin running on my grails app.

originally, I was running on grails 2.4.4. I used the default configuration

and got this error:
[Grails Elastic Search Plugin SEVERE: Unexpected transforming call sites grails elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29418419/921636)

so I upgraded to 2.5.0 as suggested in this answer.

I set the DatastoreImpl to

```
elasticsearch {
  datastoreImpl = "hibernateDatastore"
}
```

but I am getting the error that i have not specified the datastore... 
Somebody got an idea what to try ?

```
2015-06-28 00:56:11,179 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No datastore implementation specified
Message: No datastore implementation specified
    Line | Method
->>  135 | doCall                    in ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    754 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 3):

```
elasticSearch.client.mode = 'local';
elasticSearch.datastoreImpl = 'hibernateDatastore';
```

This should fix this bug if you append to `Config.groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

Following config works for me:

`elasticSearch.datastoreImpl = 'hibernateDatastore'`